# meteor js how to write a file to local disk from the server?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I want to know how to save file in local disk? Like i want to save file in c: drive using meteor. Help me to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the data on the server methods than use file system you can write the file to a local disk.

**Client side code :**

*Template code:*

```
<template name="example">
    <input type=file />
</template>
```

*Template event code:*

```
Template.example.events({
  'change input': function(ev) {  
    _.each(ev.srcElement.files, function(file) {
      Meteor.saveFile(file, file.name);
    });
  }
});
```

*Meteor.saveFile function code:*

```
/**
 * @blob (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Blob)
 * @name the file's name
 * @type the file's type: binary, text (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/FileReader#Methods) 
 *
 * TODO Support other encodings: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/FileReader#Methods
 * ArrayBuffer / DataURL (base64)
 */
Meteor.saveFile = function(blob, name, path, type, callback) {
  var fileReader = new FileReader(),
    method, encoding = 'binary', type = type || 'binary';
  switch (type) {
    case 'text':
      // TODO Is this needed? If we're uploading content from file, yes, but if it's from an input/textarea I think not...
      method = 'readAsText';
      encoding = 'utf8';
      break;
    case 'binary': 
      method = 'readAsBinaryString';
      encoding = 'binary';
      break;
    default:
      method = 'readAsBinaryString';
      encoding = 'binary';
      break;
  }
  fileReader.onload = function(file) {
    Meteor.call('saveFile', file.srcElement.result, name, path, encoding, callback);
  }
  fileReader[method](blob);
}
```

**Server side code :**

```
/**
 * TODO support other encodings:
 * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7329128/how-to-write-binary-data-to-a-file-using-node-js
 */
Meteor.methods({
  saveFile: function(blob, name, path, encoding) {
    var path = cleanPath(path), fs = __meteor_bootstrap__.require('fs'),
      name = cleanName(name || 'file'), encoding = encoding || 'binary',
      chroot = Meteor.chroot || 'public';
    // Clean up the path. Remove any initial and final '/' -we prefix them-,
    // any sort of attempt to go to the parent directory '..' and any empty directories in
    // between '/////' - which may happen after removing '..'
    path = chroot + (path ? '/' + path + '/' : '/');

    // TODO Add file existance checks, etc...
    fs.writeFile(path + name, blob, encoding, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        throw (new Meteor.Error(500, 'Failed to save file.', err));
      } else {
        console.log('The file ' + name + ' (' + encoding + ') was saved to ' + path);
      }
    }); 

    function cleanPath(str) {
      if (str) {
        return str.replace(/\.\./g,'').replace(/\/+/g,'').
          replace(/^\/+/,'').replace(/\/+$/,'');
      }
    }
    function cleanName(str) {
      return str.replace(/\.\./g,'').replace(/\//g,'');
    }
  }
});
```